# Spring boot @Configuration with @ConditionalOnClass not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I have created a module with `JMSConnectionConfig` as given below.

```
@ConditionalOnClass(JmsTemplate.class)
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class JMSConnectionConfig {
    ...............
    ...............
    ...............
}
```

I have two SpringBoot apps. One application requires JMS configuration with Spring JMS dependency and the other application doesn't require JMS. For that reason, I have added `@ConditionalOnClass` annotation on `JMSConnectionConfig` to load when it finds `JmsTemplate` in the class path. Though the `JMSConnectionConfig`  dependency was there in the classpath for second application, I was expecting the bean won't load as the JmsTemplate will not be there in the class path. But, I am not getting that behavior. **What is the configuration I am missing here to load the bean conditionally?**

Comment: How is this class getting activated? Component scanning? Note that Boot _already_ has JMS configuration built in, so you might consider eliminating your class entirely and using the out-of-the-box support.

Comment: Yes, I am doing component scanning.  I gave example with JMS Configuration. But, I want to load a bean conditionally. That is my main intent.

Comment: If you're loading this class via component scanning, then the auto-configuration rules aren't being applied. Read [the docs on auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-test-autoconfig).